# How to set map to cache with jedis

Tags: java, dictionary, jedis

I am newer to use jedis not spring-data-redis.
now I want to set Map to cache with jedis. 
what should I do? who can help me? thank you!

Comment: like  Map<String,Map<String ,String>>

Comment: "who can help me?" -- I can, but I won't

Answer (score -2, accepted):

we can trans the Map to byte[] with serialization then set map to cache. or use gson change map into string

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a composite map M (instance of `HashMap<String,Map<String ,String>>`) in java with values:

```
A -> (A1 -> A1V; A2 -> A2V) 
B -> (B1 -> B1V; B2 -> B2V)
```

Considering it only one single map the value A1V has a composite key (A, A1) and B2V has a composite key (B, B2) and so on.

Considering that Redis is also a big map (key-value store) and map M needs to be stored under the key K (K - > M) the value A1V has a Redis composite key (K, A, A1) and B2V has a Redis composite key (K, B, B2) and so on.

So you can store your simple values in Redis simply designing your key-namespace like:

```
Keys:     Values:
K:A:A1 -> A1V
K:A:A2 -> A2V
K:B:B1 -> B1V
K:B:B2 -> B2V
```

where the keys are concatenated strings with separators.

If your simple values like A1V are not strings but a kind of objects like instances of class User, you can use Redis type Hash: http://redis.io/topics/data-types

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values, so they
>   are the perfect data type to represent objects

Comment: Thank you in advance. Your idea  is good, but it  is not suitable

Answer (score 0):

Try enableComplexMapKeySerialization, it works well in my case.

```
GsonBuilder gsonbuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonbuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
gson = gsonbuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Comment: what is this code about?